# Raw Ethernet PF_PACKET issue on localhost

Tags: raw-ethernet

I am working on raw ethernet programming in c. I have two files client and server  which are running on localhost. I am using my own protocol number for communication in socket().

On the client side i have follwing code

```
    s = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 61187);  
    unsigned char dest_mac[6]= {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};  
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;

        socket_address.sll_family   = PF_PACKET;
        socket_address.sll_protocol = 61187;
        socket_address.sll_ifindex  = ifindex;
        socket_address.sll_hatype   = ARPHRD_ETHER;
        socket_address.sll_pkttype  = PACKET_BROADCAST;
        socket_address.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;
        socket_address.sll_addr[0]  = dest_mac[0];
        socket_address.sll_addr[1]  = dest_mac[1];
        socket_address.sll_addr[2]  = dest_mac[2];
        socket_address.sll_addr[3]  = dest_mac[3];
        socket_address.sll_addr[4]  = dest_mac[4];
        socket_address.sll_addr[5]  = dest_mac[5];
        socket_address.sll_addr[6]  = 0x00;
        socket_address.sll_addr[7]  = 0x00;
```

and then i send some data as follows

```
sent = sendto(s, buffer, ETH_HEADER_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
```

On the server side i do socket creation as in client and i am doing recvfrom as follows

```
length = recvfrom(s, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

But i dont receive any packet on server side. Could anyone let me know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your incomplete example, but I would suspect that you're using a `SOCK_RAW` where you want to use a `SOCK_DGRAM`. In your `SOCK_RAW`, the Ethernet header is assumed to be part of the `buffer` you specify, i.e. your setting of a destination address is irrelevant to the contents of the packet. With `SOCK_DGRAM`, the contents of `buffer` form the payload of the generated Ethernet frame and the header comes from your address field.

This kind of thing is fairly easy to debug when you let `tcpdump -neX` (or something equivalent with Wireshark or tshark) run while testing - you'll see exactly what packet you are generating.